# How to delete a row if one of the cells is empty

Tags: python, replace

Here is the spreadsheet :

```
Color  Name      Size
red    Apple     large
green  Apple     small
orange Orange    small
pea    Green     super small
```

Here I replace all instances of Apple with Apple_Object and delete any name that isn't apple:

```
for x in name:
    if 'Apple' not in name:
         name = name.replace(x, '')


for x in name:
    name = name.replace('Apple', 'Apple_Object')
```

> sheet.write(name):

```
Color    Name             Size
red      Apple_Object     large
green    Apple_Object     small
orange                    small
pea                       super small
```

How do I delete all rows with no name?

**Desired output:**

```
 Color    Name             Size
  red      Apple_Object     large
  green    Apple_Object     small
```

Thanks!

Comment: What datatype are you using to store the entire table?

Comment: That isn't a list. Are you reading from a sort of csv file?

Comment: `list` does not have a `replace` method, only strings do. Also modifying your list during iteration is calling for trouble

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `list` type. That makes your code confusing to read, and can lead to mysterious bugs.

Comment: No, it goes through and gets color than writes color to the list.  Then it gets the name and writes name to the list. Then gets size and writes size to the list. Then it starts a new line and repeats.

Comment: Deleting from the list (use del()) is fine during iteration if you're traversing it backwards.  But I agree, we're missing a lot of code, here, and an actual description of the data structures being used to store all this.

Comment: see the edit, I explain more. My bad I didn't specify much

Comment: You're kind of missing a [mcve]. That would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but you _still_ haven't told us what the datatype of`name` is. I guess it's a string, but it would be good if your question was a bit more explicit about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the value of apple for nothing

```
for x in list:
  if 'Apple' not in list:
     list = list.replace(x, '')
```

but you should be eliminating the current row

```
for x in list:
  if 'Apple' not in list:
     del list[index]
```

Comment: You'll want to traverse it backwards if you want to delete from it.

Comment: If you see the edit its not actually stored in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. It filters out rows that does contains an empty string leaving the rest

`result = filter(lambda x: '' not in x, list)`